# how to join correlated subquery with outer table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, updates, correlated-subquery

I have a query like this -

```
UPDATE ACTION a 
INNER JOIN subscriberinfo s ON a.subscriberId = s.id AND a.subscriberId=118  
INNER JOIN ticket t ON t.subscriberId = s.id AND s.id=118 
SET a.exceedusage = (SELECT FORMAT(((SUM(dataVolumeDownLink + dataVolumeUpLink))/1048576),2) 
                    FROM cdr c 
                    WHERE c.msisdn =12424474969 
                    AND c.msisdn = s.msisdn
                    AND c.eventDate>t.cdrEventDate 
                    AND c.eventDate < a.actionTakenOn) 
WHERE a.remark='Reason : Data limit crossed' 
AND a.exceedusage IS NULL;
```

I want to update action tables column, am I doing something wrong in this query?

Please explain me with an example that how to perform such kind of update,if possible.

Comment: sorry i haven't explained it better. Let me edit and recheck the question.

Comment: just for curiosity why are you inner joining it above ? why not below ?

Comment: @waseem I am confused in the same, please let me know how i can join it below, if possible.

Comment: What is the problem when you are running your query? What doesn't work?

Comment: @AndriyM i am not getting any output from this query, its running continuously. My tables have around 100,000 records overall.

Comment: There's no join condition between `a` and `s` and between `a` and `t` (or `s` and `t`, I don't know). Did you forget to specify them?

Comment: I have edited the query, please have a look. Result is same.

Comment: `dataVolumeDownLink` and `dataVolumeUpLink` are not aliased in the query. Could you tell us to which tables do these columns belong ?

Comment: they belong to cdr table

Comment: @AamirSohail  - you forgot to put alias on these SELECT FORMAT(((SUM(c.dataVolumeDownLink + c.dataVolumeUpLink)). try out this

Comment: @waseem - its not important to use alias if column names are unique in all, so thats not the problem. And by the way I have changed the query and its working now. And thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Please, use group by where aggregate function is there:

```
  UPDATE ACTION a 
    INNER JOIN subscriberinfo s ON a.subscriberId=118  
    INNER JOIN ticket t ON s.id=118 
    SET a.exceedusage = (SELECT FORMAT(((SUM(dataVolumeDownLink + dataVolumeUpLink))/1048576),2) 
                        FROM cdr c 
                        WHERE c.msisdn =12424474969 
                        AND c.eventDate>t.cdrEventDate 
                        AND c.eventDate < a.actionTakenOn group by c.msisdn ) 
    WHERE a.remark='Reason : Data limit crossed' 
    AND a.exceedusage IS NULL;
```

Comment: no its not working, this is the same query i posted with group by clause